# button要素内の画像をCSSでグレースケール化したい

Tags: html, css

button要素内の画像をCSSでグレースケール化したい

下記のように、button要素にdisabled属性が付けられている場合だけ、内部のimg要素の画像をグレースケール化したいです。

```
<button disabled><img src="URL"/></button>
```

グレースケール化とその解除については、JavaScriptで何らかの関数を呼び出したりするのではなく、CSSでする方法を探しています。
↓こんな風に書けたら理想的です。

```
button[disabled] > img { /* ここでグレースケール化の記述 */ }
```

対象ブラウザはIE8～11、GoogleChrome(43?)です。
IE8～9なら `filter: gray`、Chromeなら`-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);`でいけるのですが、IE10～11ではどうにもならず困っています。

Comment: 英語版のS/Oで同じ質問がありました。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter 実際の例 http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/qhU7d/2/

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちょっと分からなかったのですが、SVGの`filter`要素にある、`feComposite`要素は何のためのものでしょうか。`<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" />`だけだと何か不足がありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenji Noguchiさんのコメントを参考に、IE8～11とChromeで動作するものができましたので、回答として載せておきます。

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#target').prop('disabled', function(i, d) {
    return !d;
  });
});
```

```css
#grayscale-filter {
  display: none;
}

button>.button-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

button>.button-image>img {
  width: 100%;
}

button[disabled]>.button-image>img {
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

button>.grayscale-ie10p {
  display: none;
}

button>.grayscale-ie10p>svg {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  button[disabled]>.grayscale-ie10p {
    display: block;
  }
  button[disabled]>.grayscale-other {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="grayscale-filter">
    <defs>
        <filter id="filtersPicture">
            <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<button id="toggle">toggle disabled</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<button id="target">
    <div class="button-image grayscale-other">
        <img src="http://www.google.co.jp/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-image grayscale-ie10p">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.google.co.jp/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lshr07sk/2/

※IE8だとjsfiddle見れないですが・・・